# Calculate width variable of imgs into a div

Tags: jquery, wordpress, variables, width

I want to make a carousel with Jquery,
and the img have variable width.

I know how to calculate multiple img with a **FIX** width but i don't know how calculate with **VARIABLE** width for assign a div (in this case sub_container).

This is the example:

```
    <div id="container">
          <div id="sub_container" style="width:WIDTH FROM VARIABLE WIDTH OF IMAGES">          
             <img id="#number" width="200px" src="#">
             <img id="#number" width="240px" src="#">
             <img id="#number" width="150px" src="#">
             <img id="#number" width="500px" src="#">
          </div>
    </div>
```

*REMEMBER*:
The Width of container is getting from width of window/browser.

Can you help me? :/

Thank you VERY VERY much! :(

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
$(function() {
   var width = 0;
   // Get all images in the sub container
   $("img","#sub_container").each(function () {
       // Add the width of each image
       width += $(this).width();
   });
   // Do whatever you want with the width
   $("#sub_container").width(width);
});
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/DZ9rF/

Comment: @user12932 Works for me. Added a fiddle to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.fn.sumWidths = function() {
    var sum = 0; 
    this.each(function() {
        sum += $(this).width();
    });
    return sum;
};
```

Then

```
$('#sub_container').width( $('#sub_container img').sumWidths() );
```